# Reload GridView C#

Tags: c#

I just want to know how do you guys reload the data from other form in C# which uses custom control in between.

Let me clarify things up, I have a `Form1` which has a `gridview`, I have a user control attach to it that when click it will open up `Form2`. Now, I want to refresh the `Form1` from `Form2`.

I can achieve the same result without using a custom control by having a parameter in Form2 constructor but I don't know how to design the solution that involves a custom control.

Here is my code on how to reload the Form1 gridview from the other Form

```
public class Form2
{
    private Form1 _form1;
    public Form2(Form1 db):this()
    {
        _form1=db;
    }

    void ReloadForm1()
    {
    _form1.Reload()
    }
}
```

on Form1

```
public class Form
{
    void Click()
    {
        Form2 f=new Form2(this);
        f.show()
    }

    public void Reload()
    {
        //Load Data
    }

}
```

This code is working, i just need a help how to achieve the same result with a custom control involve.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried coding something to do this? Show your code

Comment: Use the `FormClosing` event so that when Form 2 closes, it refreshes the gridview in Form1

Comment: What do you mean by "reload the data from other form"?  We don't know what that means.

Comment: What exactly are you attempting to do? do you want to repaint a custom control?

Comment: I just want to reload my gridview on Form1 from Form2.

Comment: @Rory.ap, what i mean by reload is to refresh the data. I am using datagridview to display the data. C# WinForms

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
public class Form
{
    void Click()
    {
        Form2 f=new Form2(this);
        f.closing += form2Closing;
        f.show()
    }

    public void Reload()
    {
        //Load Data
    }

    private void form2Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        Reload()
    }

}
```

Comment: I am not calling the Form2 inside form1, i am calling the form2 from a userControl which is just attach to  form1. Hope that clear things out.

Comment: so add an event handler on the usercontrol, the usercontrol will get the event form2Closing and will raise the event for the Form

Answer (score 0):

You can call reload() after the form2 closes - see below:

(Form1)

```
public class Form
{
    void Click()
    {
        Form2 f=new Form2(this);
        f.ShowDialog();
        reload();
    }

    public void Reload()
    {
        //Load Data
    }

}
```

Comment: that will reload after the show not after the close of the form